# Odoo 9 and opportunities

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I follow some tutorials to master CRM module, but I face one problem , I can't find "opportunities" sub menu in sales menu and I don't know how to resolve it.

Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In this Image You can See Where is "Opportunity" menu and Also Click on "Next Activities" and Create new Opportunity:

[image]

2) In Side bar Click On "Your Pipeline" And Create new Opportunity:

[image]

3) click on "Next Activities" Directly you go on Opportunity Tree View. and create a new Opportunity.

Comment: thanks for your reply, this solve my problem.is there any  way to have "opportunities" in sales menu likes "leads" without going through dashboard.

Comment: so i guess that these are the only ways to access to opportunities menu, and there is no way to have the "opportunities" separately in one menu like we "leads".

Comment: yes there is available one Menu  Next Activities is as Opportunities .

Comment: so "Next Activities" means "Opportunities " in odoo ?